# Xpath question-Unable to traverse from one td to another td

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I traversed till a[@data-subjectid='446'], I want to traverse after that to td/label/div(Slider round)- In the screenshot below.
I wrote xpath below and not recognizing the element
("//table[@id='subjects_grid']/tbody//tr[@class='subject-status-off']/td//a[@data-subjectid='446']/td//label[@class='switch']/div")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZS83.png)

Please help writing me xpath until slider round.

Comment: /following::td should fix it for you. There's no child element td for that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using xpath axes.

```
("//table[@id='subjects_grid']/tbody//tr[@class='subject-status-off']/td//a[@data-subjectid='446']/parent::td/following-sibling::td/label[@class='switch']/div")
```

Comment: I want to add subjectid in the xpath to click the  slideraround for that particular subject.  Can you please help me to write xpath with subjectid?

Comment: I just edited it but it just the ideal of using xpath axes to achieve your goal. If you provide me link to your website i could write you correct xpath to the problem. Check this link for me detail [https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp]

Comment: Awesome. It worked like a charm, Can you explain me after a[@data-subjectid='446']? Just want to understand for future

Comment: [parent::td] it will selects the parent of the current node: a[@data-subjectid='446']. [following-sibling::td] Selects all siblings after the current node. So the flow of this xpath is: td -> a[@data-subjectid='446'] -> parent::td (go back to the parent td tag) -> following-sibling::id (select the td tag next to current td tag ) -> label -> div. Sorry for my bad english. You should read the link i send and do some practice. The xpath axes is a very powerful tool.